# Syntax error on simple init script for debian

Tags: bash, shell, debian, init

It seems like the colons should be there from the tutorials I am reading, and yet it is telling me to remove them?

```
/etc/init.d/uwsgi: 27: /etc/init.d/uwsgi: Syntax error: ";;" unexpected
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          uwsgi
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Description:       This script manages uWSGI.
### END INIT INFO

DAEMON=/var/www/app/venv/bin/uwsgi
PIDFILE=/var/run/uwsgi.pid
DAEMON_ARGS="--ini /var/www/app/conf/uwsgi/app.ini --pidfile /var/run/uwsgi.pid"

. /lib/init/vars.sh
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case "$1" in
  start)
  echo "Starting"
  start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
    || return 1
  start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- \
    $DAEMON_ARGS 1> /dev/null 2>&1 \
    || return 2
  esac
  ;;
  stop)
  echo "Stopping"
  start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=QUIT/30/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --name uwsgi
  RETVAL="$?"
  [ "$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2
  start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry=0/30/KILL/5 --exec $DAEMON
  [ "$?" = 2 ] && return 2
  rm -f $PIDFILE
  return "$RETVAL"
  esac
  ;;
  status)
  status_of_proc "$DAEMON" "uwsgi" && exit 0 || exit $?
  ;;
  reload)
  echo "Reloading"
  start-stop-daemon --stop --signal 1 --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --name uwsgi
  return 0
  ;;
  *)
  echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/uwsgi {start|stop|status|reload|force-reload}" >&2
  exit 3
  ;;
esac
```

Comment: `esac` is for the close of a `case`, not for the close of each condition.

Comment: That's it! Shellcheck said the same

Comment: Ah, so I can remove all but the last, is that what you are saying?

Comment: @jimmy yes; they're causing the syntax errors.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about shell check either. Please add as an answerr so I can accept

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of your other question on this theme (migrated from another Stack Exchange site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper syntax for the `case` statement is:

```
case expression in
    pattern1)
    statements
    ;;
    pattern2)
    statements
    ;;
esac
```

i.e. just closed with a single `esac` at the end. Anything else is just going to cause a syntax error.

You can feed scripts into [ShellCheck](http://shellcheck.net/), which does on-line script checking and will indicate where the syntax error is (which you can highlight in the input that you're pasting in here).